# Wondering how to set filters in Vaadin's "TableQuery"

Tags: java, data-binding, filter, database-connection, vaadin

I've created a database connection in Vaadin. After I've built the JDBCConnectionPool I created a TableQuery like this:

```
            TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("STRING", pool, new OracleGenerator());
```

However, this is pretty successful because I'm able to get the appropriated entities (the query returns the whole table).

The problem is that I want to filter this query. I'm really disappointed about the documentation regarding this topic. The javadoc of the TableQuery.setFilters() method states, that we need to have a List containing the filters.

My approach so far:

```
            List<Filter> filter = new ArrayList<Filter>();
            filter.add(new Equal("SURNAME", "SMITH"));
            tq.setFilters(filter);
```

This does just nothing. It even doesn't provoke an exception. The code just works as it would without the block mentioned above.

Does anyone have some input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that was easy. I've just mistaken the concept. You've to filter the container.

Like this:

```
            // tq is the TableQuery (see code snippet provided in the question)
            SQLContainer container = new SQLContainer(tq);
            container.addContainerFilter(new Equal("SURNAME", "SMITH"));
```

May help someone to avoid this "trap" ;P